# Allocating an array in a struct in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I am trying to allocate an array of structs within a struct.  Here is my code:

```
struct t_nd {
  double stuff;
};

struct t_nwork {
  struct t_nd *nds;
};

struct t_nwork net;

// need to allocate the nds array to be of size 10
```

tried this but failed:

```
t_nd* net.nds = new t_nd[10];
```

someone said try a vector, so I tried:

```
vector<t_node> net.nodes(10);
```

but yet again failed dismally.

Comment: Can you add language?

Comment: You appear to be struggling with some fundamentals. You might want to pick up some [good C++ books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Answer (score 2):

> someone said try a vector, so I tried:... but failed

You can use vector as shown below. In the shown program, we have a data member called `nds` of type `vector<t_nd>`. Also, we have a constructor that has a parameter of type `std::size_t`.

```
struct t_nd {
  double stuff;
};
struct t_nwork {
  //data member of type std::vector<t_nd>
  std::vector<t_nd> nds;
  
  //constructor to set size of vector 
  t_nwork(std::size_t psize): nds(psize)
  {
      
  }
};


int main()
{
    //create object of type t_nwork whose nds have size 10
    t_nwork net(10);
}
```

[Working demo](https://onlinegdb.com/Z7sNEiHAQ)

##### Method 2

Here we don't have any constructor to set the size of the vector.

```
struct t_nd {
  double stuff;
};

struct t_nwork {
  //data member of type std::vector<t_nd>
  std::vector<t_nd> nds;
  
};

//create object of type t_nwork whose nds have size 10
t_nwork net{std::vector<t_nd>(10)};
```

[Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/WlGCXoGVD)

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution:

```
#include <iostream>

struct t_nd {
    double stuff;
};

struct t_nwork {
    t_nd* nds;
};

int main() {
    t_nwork net;
    net.nds = new t_nd[100];
    // ...
    delete[] net.nds;
}
```

This is the solution using vector:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct t_nd {
    double stuff;
};

struct t_nwork {
    std::vector<t_nd> nds;
};

int main() {
    t_nwork net;
    net.nds.resize(10);
    net.nds[1];
}
```